# Understanding the code behind Host Card Emulation and APDUs

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu, hce

I have just started making an app that uses Host Card Emulation (HCE) and I have done various bits and pieces. I need the app to make the phone behave like a card whilst another phone behaves like an NFC reader and scans it and vice versa in order to exchange a very small piece of information  - an ID number.

I have done a few functional units such as the ProcessCommandApdu and defining the AID but I don't really understand how it works.

This is my code so far...

@TargetApi(19)
public class MainActivity extends HostApduService {

```
@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {

}

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
    String inboundApduDescription;
    byte[] responseApdu;

    if (Arrays.equals(AID_SELECT_APDU, commandApdu)) {
        inboundApduDescription = "Application selected";
        Log.i("HCEDEMO", inboundApduDescription);
        byte[] answer = new byte[2];
        answer[0] = (byte) 0x90;
        answer[1] = (byte) 0x00;
        responseApdu = answer;
        return responseApdu;

    }
    return commandApdu;
}

private static final byte[] AID_SELECT_APDU = {
        (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0xA4,
        (byte) 0x04,
        (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0x07,
        (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0x00
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    TerminalFactory terminalFactory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
    try {
        for (CardTerminal terminal : terminalFactory.terminals().list()) {
            System.out.println(terminal.getName());
            try {
                Card card = terminal.connect("*");
                CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
                System.out.println("SelectAID ");
                CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(SelectAID);
                ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
                byte recv[] = response.getBytes();
                for (int i = 0; i < recv.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(String.format("%02X", recv[i]));
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            catch (CardException e){}


        }
    }
    catch(CardException e){

    }
}
```

}

```
public class ReaderActivity {
public static byte[] SelectAID = new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0x07,
        (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x00, (byte)
        0x00
};
```

}

What do the bytes represent e.g. 0x00, 0xA4 and how do I convey my own information (an ID number) through the APDU?

What more do I have to add ?

I have based my code on the following tutorial https://www.slideshare.net/ChienMingChou/hce-tutorialv-v1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APDUs are specified in part 4 of the ISO 7816 standard - that's where you will find what does each byte represent (class byte, operation code, parameter bytes, etc). `0xA4` for example means `SELECT command`.

My recommendation is to go to the [GlobalPlatform website](http://www.globalplatform.org/) and download the Card Specification - you'll have to register, but it is free. Chapter 11 of that Card Spec contains a lot of information about APDU encoding, the most interesting APDU commands and responses to manage cards, etc. That will help you get started and give you ideas about what APDU commands you can design for your application.

Comment: Ok thanks that spec does help a lot. Will I need to register my actual AID or anything like that when I create my app ? I was reading the other day some stuff in one of the ISO specs saying you have to register an AID like Visa and Mastercard and pay lots of money. Is this true ?

Comment: Registering your AID is not mandatory - companies can buy a prefix called RID (the "Registered Application ID", here is a list https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/212-emv-rid ) As they say here https://www.ansi.org/other_services/registration_programs/rid if the RID (and therefore the AID) begins with 'F' is considered proprietary and there is no need to register it.